# Целесообразность универсализации функций работы с БД

Tags: django-orm, оптимизация

Здравствуйте.

Сложилась весьма сложная, на мой взгляд, ситуация при разработке, а точнее, допиливании некоего проекта на Django.

Есть **ряд функций, для работы с базой данных**, основанных, в основном, на **Django-ORM**. Функции по большому счету не сложные, с точки зрения оптимизации там делать почти нечего, за исключением допиливания поведения самой ORM, которое, в итоге, даже ничтожную его (имхо) "абстрактную" модель сведет на нет (именно к ней почему-то руководство апеллирует каждый раз, когда речь заходит о выборе ORM или Raw-Queries). Но на данный момент я больше обеспокоен по другому поводу (правда, с удовольствием так же зачитаюсь мнениями насчет ORM или Raw-Queries).

Так вот, имеется ряд функций, написанных **на "все случаи жизни"**. Содержат **от 5-ти формальных параметров**. Используются данные функции в разных уголках системы, скажем, навскидку, каждая в 10 других функциях более высокого уровня. В итоге нередко приходится допиливая одну часть функции, проверять, а не сделал ли хуже где-то еще.

Мой вопрос, "*а не разбить ли функцию на под-функции или не написать ли отдельную (плюс-минус) функцию для каждой из функций более высокого уровня*", встретил бурю негодования с рассказом, что **так все и должно быть**, функция одна - это хорошо. Т.е. в случае каких-либо правок в БД, необходимо поправить всего лишь одну функцию, а не десять. Впрочем, я вполне согласен, что полное копирование кода одной функции в другую просто бессмысленно, но хотя бы каким-то образом выполнить разбиение функции на мелкие функциональные части просто необходимо. И вот данная точка зрения приходится не по-душе руководству.

1. Что вы думаете по поводу ORM vs. Raw-Queries?
2. Где найти тот баланс между "количество функций работы с БД" и "количество зависимых от них функций"?
3. Каким образом вы уговариваете начальство, которое "больше знает"?
4. Есть ли вариант best-practices для реализации сложных моделей для Django?

*P.S.
Надеюсь, что описал все достаточно толково, иначе, ткните пальцем пожалуйста, что не понятно, забываю русскую речь.*

Answer (score 1):

1. [KISS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Принцип_KISS). Там, где ORM позволяет решить задачу одной строкой кода, глупо им не пользоваться. На практике встречаются сильно более сложные и модели и запросы. И попытки кровь из носу реализовать логику с помощью ORM сводят пользу от ORM к нулю - получается и сложнее и многословнее.
2. [DRY](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don’t_repeat_yourself). Функций должно быть ровно столько, сколько необходимо. Дублирование функционала в разных местах, как вы правильно заметили, ухудшает поддерживаемость, читаемость и т.д.
3. они и правда знают больше и отвечают в итоге за продукт. если вы не принимаете участия во всех этапах жизни продукта, то вам, возможно не видна общая картина. Впрочем, "начальник - идиот" тоже бывает.

ЗЫ Любую проблему при проектировании можно решить путём введения дополнительного абстрактного слоя (кроме проблемы слишком большого количества абстрактных слоёв).